# How to convert hex number to bin in Swift?

Tags: swift, binary, hex

I have string variable:
var str = "239A23F"
How do I convert this string to a binary number?
`str.toInt()` does not work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `NSScanner()` from the Foundation framework:

```
let scanner = NSScanner(string: str)
var result : UInt32 = 0
if scanner.scanHexInt(&result) {
    println(result) // 37331519
}
```

Or the BSD library function `strtoul()`

```
let num = strtoul(str, nil, 16)
println(num) // 37331519
```

As of *Swift 2 (Xcode 7),* all integer types have an

```
public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)
```

initializer, so that a pure Swift solution is available:

```
let str = "239A23F"
let num = Int(str, radix: 16)
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Maybe I am missing something, but how is "37331519" binary?

Comment: @iOSBlacksmith: Here “binary number” again means an integer (with binary representation in memory). Note that `Int` conforms to the `BinaryInteger` protocol. – The terms “integer”, “decimal”, “binary number” etc are not always used coherently. – This applies to your last remark here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790660/how-to-convert-a-binary-to-decimal-in-swift/26810937?noredirect=1#comment130003632_26810937 as well.