# In Swift, how to convert String to Int for base 2 though base 36 like Long.parseLong in Java?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I convert a String to a Long in Swift?

In Java I would do `Long.parseLong("str", Character.MAX_RADIX)`.

Comment: You want to write it in java or in swift?

Comment: @Shuo He already supplied the Java code, so he means Swift.

Comment: I want write it in Swift!

Comment: Do you need a radix other than 10?

Comment: @vacawama based on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/long_parselong.htm, there is no such option for parseLong. So I assume it is base 10.

Comment: @Shuo, notice that they are calling `parseLong` with 2 parameters.  The second is the `radix` and I believe Character.MAX_RADIX is 36, so they are trying to parse a base 36 number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790660/how-to-convert-a-binary-to-decimal-in-swift), you can use the standard library function strtoul():

```
let base36 = "1ARZ"
let number = strtoul(base36, nil, 36)
println(number) // Output: 60623
```

The third parameter is the radix. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) for how the function handles whitespace and other details.

Answer (score 3):

We now have these conversion functions built-in in Swift Standard Library:

Encode using base 2 through 36: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997127-init
Decode using base 2 through 36: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2924481-init

Answer (score 0):

Here is `parseLong()` in Swift.  Note that the function returns an `Int?` (optional `Int`) that must be unwrapped to be used.

```
// Function to convert a String to an Int?.  It returns nil
// if the string contains characters that are not valid digits
// in the base or if the number is too big to fit in an Int.

func parseLong(string: String, base: Int) -> Int? {
    let digits = Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

    var number = 0
    for char in string.uppercaseString {
        if let digit = find(digits, char) {
            if digit < base {
                // Compute the value of the number so far
                // allowing for overflow
                let newnumber = number &* base &+ digit

                // Check for overflow and return nil if
                // it did overflow
                if newnumber < number {
                    return nil
                }
                number = newnumber
            } else {
                // Invalid digit for the base
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            // Invalid character not in digits
            return nil
        }
    }
    return number
}

if let result = parseLong("1110", 2) {
    println("1110 in base 2 is \(result)")  // "1110 in base 2 is 14"
}

if let result = parseLong("ZZ", 36) {
    println("ZZ in base 36 is \(result)")   // "ZZ in base 36 is 1295"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I found a standard library function strtoul() to achieve this situation

Answer (score -3):

Swift ways:

```
"123".toInt() // Return an optional
```

C way:

```
atol("1232")
```

Or use the NSString's integerValue method

```
("123" as NSString).integerValue
```