# Is there a way to turn a binary string into a int

Tags: swift, string, binary, integer

so I have a string like this `0b00001` is there a way to turn that into an Int, I tried something like this,

```swift
let string = "0b0001"
let int = Int(string)
```

but since there is a "b" in the string to specify that it is binary it sets `int` to `nil`.

Is there any way to turn the contents of `string` into an int?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26790660/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use BinaryInteger generic initializer but you need to drop the "0b" prefix:

```
init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = 10) where S : StringProtocol
```

---

```
let str = "0b0101"
let int = Int(str.dropFirst(2), radix: 2)   // 5
```