# How to convert Hexadecimal or Decimal to Binary in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, binary, hex

As far I searched there is no API to convert *hexadecimal* to *decimal* or *binary*

Is there any workarounds ?

Comment: You have tagged this both [objective-c] and [swift], so what are you looking for? – Here is a Swift example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284223/how-to-convert-hex-number-to-bin-in-swift (I am sure that there exist more answers for both languages).

Comment: Here is for objective C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194528/how-to-convert-hex-to-binary-iphone

Comment: To binary its fine But decimal ?

Comment: Please give an example of your input and the expected output (and what you have tried so far).

Comment: @NaveenKumar please check my answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are methods to convert into binary and hexadecimal ( If you are expecting string from integer value.)

**1) To convert into binary**

```
- (NSString *)binaryStringWithInteger:(NSInteger)value
{
    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
    while (value)
   {
    [string insertString:(value & 1)? @"1": @"0" atIndex:0];
    value /= 2;
   }
   return string;
}
```

**2) To convert into hexadecimal**

Hexadecimal is just a way of displaying an integer.

if you want to create a string that is the hexadecimal representation of an integer, you can use this code:

```
- (NSString *)hexFromInt:(NSInteger)val
{
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%X", val];
}
```